Running laravel application on AWS EC2
ss of my webpage
getting this error, even after trying multiple permission changes and ownership changes.
I am trying to run a laravel application in my ec2 instance, after installing all the dependencies and running composer install and finishing with the migrations and changing the value of .env file with db details it shows storage not able to access.
I have tried giving storage and bootstrap 775 persmission and also changing the ownership to www-data:www-data to storage. Still the error is persisting.
permission of storage
I need to run the Laravel application without any error.

the folder that it's trying to write in is storage/logs giving permission to just storage won't do anything if the logs folder still belongs to the wrong user

Make sure you chown -R for storage, so that it fixes the permissions for everything below it

@apokryfos I have used sudo chmod -R 777 storage and also changed the ownership using sudo chown -R www-data:www-data storage

@aynber Yes i have used the same, but still the error persists.

Check if there is a log file there already and check its current permissions. It's possible some background process running as a different user may be logging things in the interim
